# How to use VectorPlot3D to visualize a solution of Navier-Stokes equations in cylindrical coordinates?

Tags: plotting, finite-element-method, coordinate-transformation, fluid-dynamics

I try to solve axially symmetric Navier-Stokes equations in cylindrical coordinates. I have successfuly solved the equations, but I have troubles when I try to plot the solution, as VectorPlot3D does not support cylindrical coordinates. I have tried to substitue `[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], ArcTan[x, y], z]` instead of `[r, \[Phi], z]` or to use `CoordinateTransform`, but I did not find a way how to make it work.

Plotting attempts:

```
cylinder = Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2*radius}}, radius];

VectorPlot3D[{rVel[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], ArcTan[x, y], z], \[Phi]Vel[
   Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], ArcTan[x, y], z], 
  zVel[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], ArcTan[x, y], z]}, {x, y, z} \[Element] 
  cylinder, PlotLegends -> Automatic, VectorScaling -> Automatic]

VectorPlot3D[{rVel, \[Phi]Vel, zVel} @@ 
  CoordinateTransform["Cartesian" -> "Cylindrical", {x, y, z}], {x, y,
    z} \[Element] cylinder]
```

Rest of the code:

````
ClearAll;
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];

radius = 1;
\[CapitalOmega] = Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {radius, 2*Pi, 2*radius}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[\[CapitalOmega]];
op = {-\[Mu] *(D[u[r, \[Phi], z], {r, 2}] + 
        D[u[r, \[Phi], z], {z, 2}]) + 
     u[r, \[Phi], z]/
      r^2 + \[Rho]*(u[r, \[Phi], z]*D[u[r, \[Phi], z], r] + 
        w[r, \[Phi], z]*D[u[r, \[Phi], z], z]) - (v[r, \[Phi], z])^2/
      r + D[p[r, \[Phi], z], r],
    -\[Mu] *(D[v[r, \[Phi], z], {r, 2}] + 
        D[v[r, \[Phi], z], {z, 2}]) + 
     v[r, \[Phi], z]/
      r^2 + \[Rho]*(u[r, \[Phi], z]*
         D[v[r, \[Phi], z], r] + (u[r, \[Phi], z]*v[r, \[Phi], z])/r +
         w[r, \[Phi], z]*D[v[r, \[Phi], z], z]),
    -\[Mu] *(D[w[r, \[Phi], z], {r, 2}] + 
        D[w[r, \[Phi], z], {z, 2}]) + \[Rho]*(u[r, \[Phi], z]*
         D[w[r, \[Phi], z], r] + 
        w[r, \[Phi], z]*D[w[r, \[Phi], z], z]) + D[p[r, \[Phi], z], z],
    D[u[r, \[Phi], z], r] + u[r, \[Phi], z]/r + 
     D[w[r, \[Phi], z], z]} /. {\[Mu] -> 0.1, \[Rho] -> 1};

velocity = 1;
bottomBC = 
  DirichletCondition[{u[r, \[Phi], z] == 0, 
    v[r, \[Phi], z] == velocity*r, w[r, \[Phi], z] == 0}, z == 0];
wallBC = 
  DirichletCondition[{v[r, \[Phi], z] == 0, 
    v[r, \[Phi], z] == velocity*radius, w[r, \[Phi], z] == 0}, 
   r == radius];
pressureBC = DirichletCondition[p[r, \[Phi], z] == 0, z == 2*radius];
bcs = {bottomBC, wallBC, pressureBC};

AbsoluteTiming[{rVel, \[Phi]Vel, zVel, pressure} = 
  NDSolveValue[{op == {0, 0, 0, 0}, bcs}, {u, v, w, 
    p}, {r, \[Phi], z} \[Element] mesh, 
   Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
     "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, w -> 2, p -> 1}, 
     "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.0005}}]]
```
````

Answer (score 1):

You could define functions to transform from cylindrical to cartesian coordinates and back:

```
cart2cyl[{x_, y_, z_}] := {Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], ArcTan[x, y], z};
cyl2cart[{r_, p_, z_}] := {r Sin[p], r Cos[p], z}
```

With this we may define a function, that gives the cartesian coordinates of the velocity vector as a function of cart. coord. (assuming that the solution is stored in "sol"):

```
veccart[in : {x_, y_, z_}] := (cyl = cart2cyl[in]; 
  cyl2cart @@ { 
    cyl2cart[{sol[[1]] @@ cyl, sol[[2]] @@ cyl, sol[[3]] @@ cyl}]})
```

Finally we can now plot the velocity in cartesian coordinates:

```
cylinder = Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2*radius}}, radius];
VectorPlot3D[veccart[{x, y, z}], {x, y, z} \[Element] cylinder]
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yUQV.png]

Comment: I am sorry, but this solution is not correct. The domain is not a cylinder and the solution is not axially symmetric. You can obtain a similar plot by simply using `VectorPlot3D[{rVel[r, \[Phi], z], \[Phi]Vel[r, \[Phi], z], zVel[r, \[Phi], z]}, {r, \[Phi], z} \Element] \[CapitalOmega]]`.

Comment: Even after the edit, this also does not work as the solution is not axially symmetric.

Comment: Look at your solution

Comment: What do you mean? If the solution is actually axially symmetric? It is, because the equations are axially symmetric and plot `VectorPlot[{rVel[r, 0, z], zVel[r, 0, z]}, {r, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 2}, ]` does not change when you put a different value than 0 in the second argument.